# How can I open and build previous version of flutter App with FVM

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I found really nice opensource android program in Github. (https://github.com/nn1ks/RemoteFiles)

And I thought, Only that I have to do is open source code with android studio and build or run it.

But the problem is from gradle and version something.

I search it in Google and some people said that I have to use FVM than migrate whole app because the app that I found is really old flutter program so migrate all the code is more hard.

So I decide to use FVM to use previous version of Flutter SDK. But I found that this project's directories are weird because this project has two project in it.

[image]

There is a project under RemoteFiles-master ssh_package.

Now I already installed FVM and it seems when I can checks the flutter SDK version, I can use Pub Get and build it (maybe).

But I don't know what flutter SDK version that I should use.

I checks the pubspec.yaml and there is 'version' but it seems that it for App's version.
And I found the environment part but I cannot understand what SDK should I use. I search the flutter SDK and latest stable version of SDK is 2.0.5 and I can't understand How `sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"` can applies this version.

Is there anyone knows how to open and build this project? I already tried various time to remove Android Studio and SDK's but it's not working.

```
version: 0.1.0+12

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FVM allows you to pin any version so there is not a need to migrate.

I see the app latest commit was on Oct 10th 2019.

If you use the command `fvm releases` it will show their number and the release date. Based on that I would try `fvm use v1.10.7`